# All form must be setVisible when form1 is active

Tags: java, jframe

I have three forms form1, form2, and form3. I want when Form1 is opening, all forms must be closed (`setVisible (false)`), except for Form1. so, when Form1 is active, then only open Form1

how can i do it?

Comment: Who opens Form1? He should hide the other ones.

Comment: Show us your actual structure. You have some class that knows all forms open? Are you using JDesktopPane?

Comment: Form1 like login form, so when the login screen is open then all forms must be closed.

@sergio: i don't use JDesktopPane

Comment: How are you controlling the opened forms? If you store the opened form in a list it will be easy to close.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe just check if form1 `isVisible(form1)` and if so, just `setVisible(false)`. Is this what you want?

And another thing comes in my mind. Depends what you want to do, maybe use `dispose()` instead of `setVisible()`.

Hope I could help.

Comment: just something like `if (isVisible(form1)) then form1.setVisible(false)`

you write in java right?